# Safari desconfigurado, não carrega css

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-browser, safari, display

O Header do meu site, está abrindo desconfigurado no Safari 8.0.8, ele não está pegando o css:

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-ms-grid-row-align: center;
align-items: center;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo e conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Safari antes do 10 precisa do prefixo `-webkit`, tente isto:

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flexbox;
display: flex;

-ms-flex-align: center;
-ms-grid-row-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;

-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, deu certo!